# Is SharpDevelop free to use by companies or in companies?

Tags: license-notice

I would like to ask whether SharpDevelop and MVS (community edition) are free to use by companies or in companies?

Do I need to buy them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Default.aspx) is an open source application that is free for anyone to use, it is released under the GPL.

MVS - (Microsoft Visual Studio) - is a different matter, from [the licensing page](https://www.visualstudio.com/license-terms/mlt553321/) -

> If you are an **individual** working on your own applications ... you may use the software to develop and test those applications.
>
> If you are an **organization**, your users may use the software as follows:
>
> -Any number of your users may use the software to develop and test applications released under Open Source Initiative (OSI) approved open source software licenses.
>
> -Any number of your users may use the software to develop and test extensions to Visual Studio.
>
> -Any number of your users may use the software to develop and test device drivers for the Windows operating system.
>
> -Any number of your users may use the software to develop and test your applications as part of online or in person classroom training and education, or for performing academic research.
>
> -If none of the above apply, and you are also not an enterprise (that is `<250` pcs or users and `<$1M` annual revenue), then up to 5 of your individual users can use the software concurrently to develop and test your applications.

So if you are only using it to develop open source projects, device drivers, MVS extensions or for educational purposes, then you are free to use it. Otherwise, a company can use it free for up to 5 concurrent developers, more than that and you need to purchase a professional or enterprise license.